# matlab, performing k-means of 6 partitions on 3D coordinates

Tags: matlab

I have created a matrix A, in the following way:

```
A = [X; Y; D]
```

`X`, `Y`, and `D` are `1 X 93` lists representing the set of X, Y, Z coordinates on which I would like to perform k-means.

I would like to cluster on 6 partitions, but upon calling k-means like this:

```
kmeans(A,6)
```

I get the error:

```
Error using kmeans (line 262)
X must have more rows than the number of clusters.
```

Why does this error appear? If I am approaching this problem of performing k-means on a 3-D matrix then what is another way of approaching it?

***Note***: clustering on 3 partitions will work - anything higher will not work

Comment: `kmeans(A', 6)`. `A` needs to be `n`x`p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [in the document](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html), each column shows the variable, and each row shows the observation. The current `A` is a `3x93` matrix. It means you have 3 observation in the space wtih 93 dimension. Therefore, you should concatenate the three matrix Like the following:

```
 newA = [X.' Y.' D.']; // a matrix with 93x3 dimensions
```

Then apply k-means algorithm on the `newA`, `kmeans(newA, 6)`.